# "Element not found." error upon raising PropertyChanged UWP Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

Upon raising PropertyChanged in a UWP Xamarin application, I get a "System.Exception: Element not found." error. This works fine on Android Xamarin, but for some strange reason UWP is having trouble here. The error is raised on the `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs((propertyName)));` line.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;

namespace LemonadeClient.UI.ViewModels
{
    public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs((propertyName)));
        }

        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(storage, value))
            {
                return false;
            }
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think Element not found is part of a Xml Response.  I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and capture the first request and response from both UWP and Android.  I suspect the response will have a bad status instead of a 200 OK you will be getting an error like 400 or 500.  A lot of people have been having issue recently with the TLS authentication and you may also be having same issue.

Comment: @jdweng how did you deduce that this has anything to do with networking? Scornz, please add the full stack trace to your post, we are missing debug information to go off. Your BaseViewModel looks fine and is very common implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @Cheesebaron : The namespace is LemonadeClient (CLIENT) which implies a network connection.

Comment: Sorry your logic seems to be flawed. Just because "client" is in the namespace doesn't imply that _any_ network activity is being done. Sure, it might at some point do something on the network, but you can't be certain it is involved in this particular case. So unless OP mentions it, I don't think it is relevant.

Comment: The issue is more likely to be somewhere in the XAML. Some resource in a ResourceDictionary or the likes missing or path to it is wrong.

Comment: The BaseViewModel looks correct, could you share a code sample to reproduce this issue?